# As I can register an intent to listen when the NFC switch to on / off?

Tags: android, widget, toggle, nfc

I am making a widget that lets go NFC settings and activate it, now I just need to know how to register an intent in the NFC onReceive whether a change on / off.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        manager = (NfcManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NFC_SERVICE);
        adapter = manager.getDefaultAdapter();


        //OR        
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) 
        {   
            actualizar(context);
        }

                //OR
        if (intent.getAction().equals("ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGE")) 
        {   

            actualizar(context);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can detect changes to NFC settings once your app is created and resumed. See [this](http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/source/browse/ndeftools-util/src/org/ndeftools/util/activity/NfcDetectorActivity.java) example.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such a broadcast event. Try reading the logs, this would work but is very unreliable and fragmented. Alternatively you can check the state of things using [NfcAdapter.isEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#isEnabled()) call at specific points in your app.